# How to get the query string by javascript?

Tags: javascript, query-string

How to extract the query string from the URL in javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can easily build a dictionary style collection...

```
function getQueryStrings() { 
  var assoc  = {};
  var decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, " ")); };
  var queryString = location.search.substring(1); 
  var keyValues = queryString.split('&'); 

  for(var i in keyValues) { 
    var key = keyValues[i].split('=');
    if (key.length > 1) {
      assoc[decode(key[0])] = decode(key[1]);
    }
  } 

  return assoc; 
}
```

And use it like this...

```
var qs = getQueryStrings();
var myParam = qs["myParam"];
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I edited your answer.  `unescape` is deprecated and should be replaced with `decodeURIComponent`, you shouldn't decode the full search string because it will decode encoded ampersands or equals in the parameters e.g. `?test=fish%26chips`.  Also, I improved it to correctly decode `+` into a space.  See my answer to a similar question  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery/2880929#2880929)

Comment: @Andy No, I don't mind at all!  I agree with you. It would have handled basic query strings just fine, but now this is a more *complete* answer.

Comment: It says: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /+/: Nothing to repeat`, should I care?

Comment: @Tom Yes that is an error that needs to be fixed (It is @Andy E's fault :P)  I've updated the answer to be correct.

Comment: I was noticing that the function was failing if no parameters were specified, so I edited the function (pending peer review)! With my small addition, it would return an empty array if there are no parameters, which I think is the expected result (instead of an uncaught exception).

Comment: Splitting on '=' is incorrect behavior. -- Only the first equal sign encountered is part of the parameter name; any further equal signs (before the ampersand), should be treated as part of the value.

Answer (score 37):

If you're referring to the URL in the address bar, then

```
window.location.search
```

will give you just the query string part. Note that this includes the question mark at the beginning.

If you're referring to any random URL stored in (e.g.) a string, you can get at the query string by taking a substring beginning at the index of the first question mark by doing something like:

```
url.substring(url.indexOf("?"))
```

That assumes that any question marks in the fragment part of the URL have been properly encoded. If there's a target at the end (i.e., a # followed by the id of a DOM element) it'll include that too.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the method I use...

```
function Querystring() {
    var q = window.location.search.substr(1), qs = {};
    if (q.length) {
        var keys = q.split("&"), k, kv, key, val, v;
        for (k = keys.length; k--; ) {
            kv = keys[k].split("=");
            key = kv[0];
            val = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]);
            if (qs[key] === undefined) {
                qs[key] = val;
            } else {
                v = qs[key];
                if (v.constructor != Array) {
                    qs[key] = [];
                    qs[key].push(v);
                }
                qs[key].push(val);
            }
        }
    }
    return qs;
}
```

It returns an object of strings and arrays and seems to work quite well.
(Strings for single keys, arrays for the same key with multiple values.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to simple use following function.

```
function GetQueryStringByParameter(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

--- How to Use ---

```
var QueryString= GetQueryStringByParameter('QueryString');
```

Answer (score 1):

Very Straightforward!

```
function parseQueryString(){
    var assoc = {};
    var keyValues = location.search.slice(1).split('&');
    var decode = function(s){
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < keyValues.length; ++i) {
        var key = keyValues[i].split('=');
        if (1 < key.length) {
            assoc[decode(key[0])] = decode(key[1]);
        }
    }

    return assoc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me-

```
function querySt(Key) {

    var url = window.location.href;

    KeysValues = url.split(/[\?&]+/); 

    for (i = 0; i < KeysValues.length; i++) {

            KeyValue= KeysValues[i].split("=");

            if (KeyValue[0] == Key) {

                return KeyValue[1];

        }

    }

}

function GetQString(Key) {     

    if (querySt(Key)) {

         var value = querySt(Key);

         return value;        

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [new API called `URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) in browsers which allow you to extract and change the values of the query string.

Currently, it seems to be supported in Firefox 44+, Chrome 49+ and Opera 36+.

**Initialize/Input**

To get started, create a new URLSearchParams object. For current implementations, you need to remove the "?" at the beginning of the query string, using `slice(1)` on the querystring, [as Jake Archibald suggests](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/702474065588658176):

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.slice(1)); // myParam=12
```

In later implementations, you should be able to use it without slice:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); // myParam=12
```

**Get**

You can get params from it via the `.get` method:

```
params.get('myParam'); // 12
```

**Set**

Params can be changed using `.set`:

```
params.set('myParam', 'newValue');
```

**Output**

And if the current querystring is needed again, the `.toString` method provides it:

```
params.toString(); // myParam=newValue
```

There are a [host of other methods in this API](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

**Polyfill**

As browser support is still pretty thin, there is a [small polyfill by Andrea Giammarchi (<3kB)](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params).

Comment: This is great.  I'd like to add one other positive about this method is that it appears to decode the values automatically.  For example, if a value contains an encoded @ sign (%40), this method will return "@" instead of the encoded value of "%40".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **Javascript** :

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

### OR

You can also use the plugin **[jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)** allows to retrieve all parts of URL, including anchor, host, etc.

Usage is very simple and cool:

```
$.url().param("itemID")
```

via James&Alfa

Answer (score 0):

I have use this method

```
function getString()
{
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
var buisnessArea = getString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming "?post=1234&action=edit"

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

console.log(urlParams.has('post')); // true

console.log(urlParams.get('action')); // "edit"

console.log(urlParams.getAll('action')); // ["edit"]

console.log(urlParams.toString()); // "?post=1234&action=edit"

console.log(urlParams.append('active', '1')); // "?post=1234&action=edit&active=1"
```