# Javascript: working with query string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a Javascript function to get the query string of the browser and allow a new key/value to be passed to the function. If the key exists, I need to replace the value. Since I've spent the last 3.5 hours on this, I haven't yet gotten around to the replacing part.

So far, I'm using the answer here: [How to get the query string by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907482/getting-querystring-by-javascript) to get the query string. However, it doesn't appear to work... The URL I was testing with was: http://www.site.com/poo?drwho=tombaker&companion=k9

```
  var assoc  = {}; 
  var decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, " ")); }; 
  var queryString = location.search.substring(1);  
  var keyValues = queryString.split('&');  

  for(var i in keyValues) {  
     var key = keyValues[i].split('=');  
     assoc[decode(key[0])] = decode(key[1]);  
  }  

  if(assoc["dr"] === undefined ) { 
     // not found. todo: replace
  }
```

I'd really appricate any help! Is there any simpler way of doing this using JQuery?

Comment: What does "doesn't appear to work" mean?

Comment: As in it does nothing. It says the assoc array is empty.

Comment: When I try your code and add an `alert(assoc["drwho"]);` at the end, it outputs "tombaker", just as expected...

Comment: Tried again using jsFiddle and it works. I was using the W3C one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and pasted your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/6KcWh/5/, and added a call to `JSON.stringify()` to examine the contents of `assoc`.  It turns out `assoc` is not undefined.  But, of course `assoc.dr` is undefined, because there is no querystring argument of `dr`.  There *is* a querystring argument of `drwho`.  It looks like you were looking for the wrong querystring argument.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be misusing `for...in`.

Try converting your for loop to a standard `for (i = 0 ; i < keyValues.length; i++)` and check out some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) about what `for...in` is used for in JavaScript.

Comment: No misuse here; the "for...in" construct is a proper "for each" loop, javascript syntax

Comment: Thanks. Tried it with link and all works. I was using the W3C one.