# Get string from url using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?=332`

Is it possible to retrieve the string after `?=` using jQuery? I've been looking around Google only to find a lot of Ajax and URL vars information which doesn't seem to give me any idea.

```
if (url.indexOf("?=") > 0) {
  alert('do this');
}
```

Comment: First google result - http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Comment: Is this even valid? `?=332` *I guess it is...*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the query string by javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907482/how-to-get-the-query-string-by-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) is your friend

Specifically `window.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

First your query string is not correct, then you can simply take the substring between the indexOf '?=' + 1 and the length of the string. Please see : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

When it is easy to do without JQuery, do it with js only.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArgs = window.location.search.slice(1)
var args = myArgs.split("&") // splits on the & if that's what you need
var params = {}
var temp = []
for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    temp = args[i].split("=")
    params[temp[0]] = temp[1]
}

// var url = "http://abc.com?a=b&c=d"
// params now might look like this:
//  {
//     a: "a",
//     c: "d"
//  }
```

What are you trying to do? You very well may be doing it wrong if you're reading the URL.

Comment: `window.location.href` should just be `window.location.search`

Answer (score 0):

here is a code snippet (not by me , don't remember the source) for returning a value from a query string by providing a name

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
 var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);        
 if (!results) 
      { return 0; }        
 return results[1] || 0;
```

}