# Get the query string value and display it in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, query-string

After redirecting to home.html page, i can see the querystring values which i had given in the previous page.

```
Home.html?FirstName=dd&LastName=ee&smtButton=Submit
```

And am getting the result as:

```
firstname = undefined
lastname = undefined
age = undefined
```

Could anyone help me to solve this?

JS:

```
function getParams() {
    var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
    var params = new Array();
    if (idx != -1) {
        var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx + 1, document.URL.length).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
            params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
        }
    }
    return params;
}

params = getParams();
firstname = unescape(params["firstname"]);
lastname = unescape(params["lastname"]);
age = unescape(params["age"]);
document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");
document.write("lastname = " + lastname + "<br>");
document.write("age = " + age + "<br>");
```

Comment: can we see your code ?

Comment: @VenilAravazhi: please edit add that code to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the query string by javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907482/how-to-get-the-query-string-by-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside your function `function getParams()` you are declared variable `var params = new Array();` , I think this makes confusion for you

if a match is found , you assigned url param like `params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];`, this actually not adding value into array object. so `params.length` is **0** .but it will works as array is instance of object .. ie `params instanceof Object` is `true`

so change into basic object .. to avoid confusion

```
function getParams() {
    var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
    var params = {}; // simple js object
    .. here goes other code
}
```

and object key is case sensitive, so `FirstName` will work ..

```
firstname = unescape(params["FirstName"]);
```

to print all values try this

```
params = getParams();

for( var i in params ){
    console.log( i , params[i] );
}
```

it will print

```
FirstName dd    
LastName ee    
smtButton Submit
```

and I have modified your getParams code

```
function getParams() {

    var params = {},
        pairs = document.URL.split('?')
               .pop()
               .split('&');

    for (var i = 0, p; i < pairs.length; i++) {
           p = pairs[i].split('=');
           params[ p[0] ] =  p[1];
    }     

    return params;
}
```

Comment: Hence am getting the same result. I've to simply display those values in this page

Comment: @VenilAravazhi did tried `firstname = unescape(params["FirstName"]);` , it case sensitive

Comment: Instead of using console.log( i , params[i] );, use document.write(i," = "+ params[i] + "<br>");. Now its working properly. Your code is very helpfull to me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a querystring from the `location.search`-string to a js-object using:

```
String.prototype.q2obj = function(){
    var qArr = this.split('&')
        ,qObj = {}
        ,i =-1;
    while(++i<qArr.length) {
            qfrag = qArr[i].split('=');
            qObj[qfrag[0]] = qfrag[1];
   }
   return qObj;
};
//usage
var queryObj = location.search.substr(1).q2obj();
```

Comment: How shall i print the values which are in the object?

Comment: Any way you like it. E.g. in your case `queryObj.FirstName` would contain the value of FirstName