# How to fill H1 tag based on URL parameters

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to fill `<h1 id="fillname"></h1>` with "John" or anything if I add `?fillname=John` or `?fillname=anythingausertype`  in my URL?

Eg.: `https://www.example.com/?fillname=John` fills `<h1 id="fillname">John</h1>`

Comment: yes.. to do this you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653554/get-the-query-string-value-and-display-it-in-my-html-page) page also be helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but i do not think this is a good idea. I think there are better ways to accomplish what you want.

Do do this, first get the parameter:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var fillname = url.searchParams.get("fillname");
```

then add it to the h1 tag:

```
document.getElementById("fillname").innerHTML = fillname;
```

References:

[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search) and the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) helper object to look at URL parameters in JavaScript:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>No parameters provided</h1>

    <script>
        var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
        var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        if(urlParams.has('fillname')) {
          h1.innerText = urlParams.get("fillname");
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try this in a browser and add '?fillname=test' to the end of the filename in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Without any external library

```
const query = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
const parts = query.split("&");
const fillNameQS = parts[parts.findIndex(qs => qs.includes("fillname"))];
const value = fillNameQS.split("=")[1];
document.getElementById("#fillname").innerText = value;
```

Comment: Why not use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility)? It is a native API

Comment: I am acutally used to query-string library so I totally forgot that there is a native feature that parses query as well. Btw it' does not work in IE11 (however methods `includes` and `findIndex` that I used do not work as well)

Answer (score 1):

Use `split` to separate and create array

```js
const url = "https://www.example.com/?fillname=John";
const param = url.split('?')[1].split('=');
console.log(`<h1 id="${param[0]}">${param[1]}</h1>`)
```

---

Reference: [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1):

```
uri = window.location.search.split('=')
if (uri[0] === '?filename'){
document.getElementById('fillname').innerText = uri[1]
}
```