# Read query string parameters from inside iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, query-string

I have a web application which is inside another web application's iframe (both are done in ASP.NET MVC).

Is possible to read from the application inside the iframe the query string parameters from the parent web application using C#?

Comment: Please add information on domain (url) of each involved page - feels like you may be trying to work around same origin policy restriction using wrong methods...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to append whatever data you want to read from parent page from the page within iframe  to the iframe url itself. 
For example:

```
<iframe id="yourid" src="yourpage.aspx?parentdata=whatever_data_to_be_captured">
</iframe>
```

Now, you have to parse the src value from your iframe page to capture data.

This is a trick, and as far as I know there seems to be no direct way to access parent page data from iframe.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing also, but i wanted to know if there is another way of doing this without injecting the parameters inside the iframe src property.

Comment: No, there is no other way, else it would be a security hazzard.

Answer (score 1):

[window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.parent) should give you a reference to the Parent.There is also a [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.top) which gives the immediate parent so if your application is nested more than once you should use the right property.

From there you can do `window.parent.location` (or `window.top.location`) which has various properties of the URL requested.

To actually read the query string there are posts about that here. You just need to replace window.location with window.parent or window.top :

See the answer here : [How to get the query string by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907482/how-to-get-the-query-string-by-javascript) and much more detailed answers here: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

---

**In the Controller** : Since you said you need the query strings in the controller. You'll need to still get the query string like I've described above, then you'll pass it into the controller by putting it in the call to the `src` of the inner frame.

```
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

It all depends on how and when you're setting the `src` attribute of your inner frame. You need to somehow change it at some point.

From your outer frame you could do:

```
document.getElementById('myframe').src
 = "http://innerApplication/innerController/actionmethod/?" 
   + window.location.search;
```

Or, from inside the frame itself, you'll get the query string first, then do a redirect/reload by doing `window.[top/parent].location = the url + query string`

Then you'll read the query string as if it were the query string of the inner application.

Comment: I need to do this from code behind (before i render the page to have access to javascript)

Comment: By code behind you mean controller? You need to know the query string parameters in the controller? Then in the inner frame you need to make a request to the controller and pass the query string as a parameter to the controller from javascript, and you'll get the query string in javascript like I've described

Comment: Yes, exactly, i need to access the query strings from controller before i render the html page

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%26` instead of `&` to send to iframe, for instance:

```
Link : 2.asp?ppp=/Payam.asp?sid=1%26PID=1&sa=12313 <br>
```

In code : when I `requset.queryString("ppp")` in the parent it shows: `/Payam.asp?sid=1&PID=1`

You can use this as source of your iframe, it has two parameters:

```
<IFRAME name="My"  src='<%=ppp %>'></IFRAME>
```