# Script to append query using window.location.search not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to grab the url query string from the request variable and then append the query string to my site's entry page. However, mys script is no working. For some reason my script is not appending.

Here is my entire code:

```
<div id="full-iframe"> <iframe src="https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do?" frameborder="0" style="height: 500px; width: 680px; border: none; overflow: scroll;"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('full-iframe').src = "https://cw.na1.hgncloud.com/crossmatch/index.do" + window.location.search;
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What does it do? anything in the console? nevermind ... adding `src` to a div does not change the `src` of the iframe

Comment: You can get query string form this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907482/how-to-get-the-query-string-by-javascript