# save URL parameters into variable

Tags: javascript

How can I save the values of 'uname' and 'date' into a variable in javascript in following URL?

file:///D:/Android/Projects/ipack-schedule/www/visit.html?uname=&date=10/01/2016%2013:00:00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the query string by javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907482/how-to-get-the-query-string-by-javascript) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/4013790

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kkpwpn5z/

Comment: Or Google search: [get URL parameters javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+URL+parameters+into+variable+javascript&bav=on.2,or.&biw=1366&bih=633#q=get+URL+parameters+javascript)

Comment: Next time [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=save+URL+parameters+into+variable&oq=save+URL+parameters+into+variable&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=javascript+get+URL+parameters) first.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var uri = "file:///D:/Android/Projects/ipack-schedule/www/visit.html?uname=&date=10/01/2016%2013:00:00"

var vars = getVars(uri)
document.write(JSON.stringify(vars))

function getVars(uri) {
  var s = uri.split("?")
  if (s.length == 1) return []

  var parts = s[1].split("&")
  return parts.map(function(el) {
    return el.split("=").map(function(el){return decodeURIComponent(el)})
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : (include this code inside your js script of your file file:///D:/Android/Projects/ipack-schedule/www/visit.html?uname=&date=10/01/2016%2013:00:00)

```
$.urlParam = function(name, url) {
if (!url) {
 url = window.location.href;
}
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(url);
if (!results) { 
    return undefined;
}
return results[1] || undefined; } 
var uname = $.urlParam('uname');
var date = $.urlParam('date');
```